# How to remove painted red marks/lines on the screen?

Tags: kde, compiz, knoppix

There is some weird feature of either Compiz or KDE which allows to paint on the screen with the shortcut <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+left mouse clicks.
How do I undo, erase or remove these markings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it was simpler that I thought. Just use the right mouse click to do the opposite with the same shortcut (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>).

Answer (score 0):

Turn off "Mouse Mark" in Desktop Effects.  That's what causes them. :)